# Formatting json_encode()

Tags: php, jquery, json

I'm using json_encode() to pass data. This is my foreach loop.

```php
foreach ($result as $val) {
    $data[] = array('item'=>$val["item"]);
    $data[] = array('availability'=>$val["stocks"]););
}
```

the output is

```json
[
    {
        "item": "Anchor Butter"
    },
    {
        "availability": "no"
    },
    {
        "item": "Kraft Chedder"
    },
    {
        "availability": "yes"
    }
]
```

My question is how can I do the output as below?

```json
[
    {
        "item": "Anchor Butter",
        "availability": "no"
    },
    {
        "item": "Kraft Chedder",
        "availability": "yes"
    }
]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are adding 2 elements to the `$data` array in each iteration. Instead, try this:

```
foreach ($result as $val){
    $data[] = array('item'=>$val["item"], 'availability'=>$val["stocks"]));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$info=array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $info1= array();
    $info1["item"]=$row["item"];
    $info1["availability"]=$row["stocks"];
    array_push($info, $info1);  
}
print_r($info);
```